# Testing on multiple platforms with pytest-cpp

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I'm testing a project that has Python and C++ parts.
Both parts have unit tests, using pytest on the Python side and Catch2 on the C++ side, plus there are integration tests that are supposed to check the cooperation between the parts.
Recently I discovered pytest-cpp and it works great to create a "test all" run, with both sets of unit tests.
Integration tests are also written in pytest.
I have several testing binaries on the C++ side and pytest fixtures for compiling, running and interfacing with them from python.

Since the C++ code needs to work on multiple platforms, I'm planning to parametrize the fixtures for integration tests by a platform name and emulation method, allowing to cross compile the binaries for example for ARM64 and run them through `qemu-aarch64`.

My question is: Is there some way to hijack the test discovery done by pytest-cpp and force it to look at specific paths (with emulation wrappers) provided by my fixture, so that I can also run the C++ unit tests this way?

I've looked at the [test discovery bit of pytest-cpp](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-cpp/blob/master/src/pytest_cpp/plugin.py#L29) and I guess I could reimplement this function in my own code, but I don't see any way to parametrize pytest_collect_file by a fixture ...